# SFINAE failure with typedef in class template referring to typedef in another class template

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, type-traits, enable-if

I've been working on a way of producing compile-time information about classes that wrap other classes in C++. In a minimal example of the problem I am about to ask about, such a wrapper class:

- contains a `typedef WrappedType` defining the type of the wrapped class; and
- overloads a struct template called `IsWrapper` to indicate that it is a wrapper class.

There is a struct template called `WrapperTraits` that can then be used to determine the (non-wrapper) root type of a hierarchy of wrapped types. E.g. if the wrapper class is a class template called `Wrapper<T>`, the root type of `Wrapper<Wrapper<int>>` would be `int`.

In the code snippet below, I have implemented a recursive struct template called `GetRootType<T>` that defines a `typedef RootType` that gives the root type of wrapper type `T`. The given definition of `WrapperTraits` just contains the root type as defined by `GetRootType`, but in practice it would have some additional members. To test it, I have written an ordinary function `f` that takes an `int`, and an overloaded function template `f` that takes an arbitrary wrapper class that has `int` as its root type. I have used SFINAE to distinguish between them, by using `std::enable_if` in the function template's return type to check whether or not `f`'s argument's root type is `int` (if `f`'s argument is not a wrapper, attempting to determine its root type will fail). Before I ask my question, here is the code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


// Wrapper #######################################

template<class T>
struct Wrapper {typedef T WrappedType;};

template<class T, class Enable=void>
struct IsWrapper: std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct IsWrapper<Wrapper<T> >: std::true_type {};


// WrapperTraits #######################################

template<
  class T,
  bool HasWrapper=
    IsWrapper<T>::value && IsWrapper<typename T::WrappedType>::value>
struct GetRootType {
  static_assert(IsWrapper<T>::value,"T is not a wrapper type");

  typedef typename T::WrappedType RootType;
};

template<class T>
struct GetRootType<T,true> {
  typedef typename GetRootType<typename T::WrappedType>::RootType RootType;
};

template<class T>
struct WrapperTraits {
  typedef typename GetRootType<T>::RootType RootType;
};


// Test function #######################################

void f(int) {
  std::cout<<"int"<<std::endl;
}

// #define ROOT_TYPE_ACCESSOR WrapperTraits  // <-- Causes compilation error.
#define ROOT_TYPE_ACCESSOR GetRootType    // <-- Compiles without error.

template<class T>
auto f(T) -> 
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<int,typename ROOT_TYPE_ACCESSOR<T>::RootType>::value
  >::type
{
  typedef typename ROOT_TYPE_ACCESSOR<T>::RootType RootType;

  std::cout<<"Wrapper<...<int>...>"<<std::endl;
  f(RootType());
}


int main() {
  f(Wrapper<int>());  
  return 0; 
}
```

This compiles correctly ([try it here](https://ideone.com/yXn4Oo)) and produces the output:

```
Wrapper<...<int>...>
int
```

However, I have used `GetRootType` to determine the root type in the call to `std::enable_if`. If I instead use `WrapperTraits` to determine the root type (you can do this by changing the definition of `ROOT_TYPE_ACCESSOR`), GCC produces the following error:

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct WrapperTraits<int>’:
test.cpp:49:6:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, typename WrapperTraits<T>::RootType>::value>::type f(T) [with T = int]’
test.cpp:57:15:   required from ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, typename WrapperTraits<T>::RootType>::value>::type f(T) [with T = Wrapper<int>; typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, typename WrapperTraits<T>::RootType>::value>::type = void]’
test.cpp:62:19:   required from here
test.cpp:21:39: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
   bool HasWrapper=IsWrapper<T>::value && IsWrapper<typename T::WrappedType>::value>
```

My question is: **what rules about argument deduction in the C++ standard explain why using `WrapperTraits` causes a compilation error but using `GetRootType` doesn't?** Please note that what I want in asking this is to be able to understand *why* this compilation error occurs. I'm not so interested in what changes could be made to make it work, as I already know that changing the definition of `WrapperTraits` to this fixes the error:

```
template<
  class T,
  class Enable=typename std::enable_if<IsWrapper<T>::value>::type>
struct WrapperTraits {
  typedef typename GetRootType<T>::RootType RootType;
};

template<class T>
struct WrapperTraits<T,typename std::enable_if<!IsWrapper<T>::value>::type> {
};
```

However, if anyone can see a more elegant way of writing `f` and `WrapperTraits`, I would be very interested in seeing it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to the fact that SFINAE only happens in the "immediate context" (a term that the standard uses, but does not define well) of a template instantiation. The instantiation of `WrapperTraits<int>` *is* in the immediate context of the instantiation of `auto f<int>() -> ...`, and it succeeds. Unfortunately, `WrapperTraits<int>` has an ill-formed member `RootType`. Instantiation of that member is *not* in the immediate context, so SFINAE does not apply.

To get this SFINAE to work as you intend, you need to arrange for `WrapperTraits<int>` to *not* have a type named `RootType`, instead of having such a member but with an ill-formed definition. This is why your corrected version works as intended, although you could save some repetition by reordering:

```
template<class T, class Enable=void>
struct WrapperTraits {};

template<class T>
struct WrapperTraits<T,typename std::enable_if<IsWrapper<T>::value>::type> {
  typedef typename GetRootType<T>::RootType RootType;
};
```

I would probably code up the entire traits system as ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bb29245fb75b35a)):

```
// Plain-vanilla implementation of void_t
template<class...> struct voider { using type = void; };
template<class...Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

// WrapperTraits #######################################

// Wrapper types specialize WrappedType to expose the type they wrap;
// a type T is a wrapper type iff the type WrappedType<T>::type exists.
template<class> struct WrappedType {};

// GetRootType unwraps any and all layers of wrappers.
template<class T, class = void>
struct GetRootType {
  using type = T; // The root type of a non-WrappedType is that type itself.
};

// The root type of a WrappedType is the root type of the type that it wraps.
template<class T>
struct GetRootType<T, void_t<typename WrappedType<T>::type>> :
  GetRootType<typename WrappedType<T>::type> {};

// non-WrappedTypes have no wrapper traits.
template<class T, class = void>
struct WrapperTraits {};

// WrappedTypes have two associated types:
// * WrappedType, the type that is wrapped
// * RootType, the fully-unwrapped type inside a stack of wrappers.
template<class T>
struct WrapperTraits<T, void_t<typename WrappedType<T>::type>> {
  using WrappedType = typename ::WrappedType<T>::type;
  using RootType = typename GetRootType<T>::type;
};

// Convenience aliases for accessing WrapperTraits
template<class T>
using WrapperWrappedType = typename WrapperTraits<T>::WrappedType;
template<class T>
using WrapperRootType = typename WrapperTraits<T>::RootType;


// Some wrappers #######################################

// Wrapper<T> is a WrappedType
template<class> struct Wrapper {};
template<class T>
struct WrappedType<Wrapper<T>> {
  using type = T;
};

// A single-element array is a WrappedType
template<class T>
struct WrappedType<T[1]> {
  using type = T;
};

// A single-element tuple is a WrappedType
template<class T>
struct WrappedType<std::tuple<T>> {
  using type = T;
};
```

Although there's a lot of machinery there, and it may be more heavy-weight than you need. For example, the `WrapperTraits` template could probably be eliminated in favor of simply using `WrappedType` and `GetRootType` directly. I can't imagine you'll often need to pass a `WrapperTraits` instantiation around.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer and code! Yes, I've seen the bit about "immediate context" in section 14.8.2 paragraph 8 of the draft standard and wondered if the error might be something to do with that, but it wasn't entirely clear to me what they mean by "immediate context", so couldn't tell for sure if that was the cause.

Comment: It does say that "side effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations...are not in the 'immediate context' " though, which presumably means that the instantiation of ``GetRootType<int>`` is not in the immediate context of the attempted substitution ``T=int`` when evaluating ``f``'s signature, as your answer seems to suggest, so I'll accept your answer. It would be helpful if the standard gave a clearer definition of "immediate context" though!

Comment: Let's say there is a base class to the wrappers which is template-less, containing pure virtual methods and that you only have pointers to two of those objects. How would you do to test if the types they wrap are the same or that one is the base class of the other (for example with `std::is_base_of`)?

Answer (score 6):

The first part of your question is why it fails. The answer is that on a compile-time level, `&&` does not have short-circuit properties. This line:

```
bool HasWrapper=IsWrapper<T>::value && IsWrapper<typename T::WrappedType>::value>
```

fails because the first condition is `false`, yet the compiler tries to instantiate the second part, but `T` is `int` and hence `T::WrappedType` does not work.

---

To answer the second part of your question on how to make it easier, I think the following should make you quite happy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// Wrapper #######################################

template<class T>
struct Wrapper {};

// All you need is a way to unwrap the T, right?

template<class T>
struct Unwrap { using type = T; };

template<class T>
struct Unwrap<Wrapper<T> > : Unwrap<T> {};

// Test function #######################################

void f(int) {
  std::cout<<"int"<<std::endl;
}

// Split unwrapping and checking it with enable_if<>:
template<class T,class U=typename Unwrap<T>::type>
auto f(T) -> 
  typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<int,U>::value
  >::type
{
  std::cout<<"Wrapper<...<int>...>"<<std::endl;
  f(U());
}    

int main() {
  f(Wrapper<int>());  
  return 0; 
}
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75fd9c35e4f1d9b1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I realise now however that my question is unclear about a few things - I will update it soon.
Regarding the first part, the point is that I want the compiler to attempt to substitute ``int`` for ``T``, realise that ``T::WrappedType`` is an invalid expression, and then reject the substitution under SFINAE. This appears to be what happens when ``ROOT_TYPE_ACCESSOR`` is ``GetRootType``, and the snippet compiles. But for this does not happen when ``ROOT_TYPE_ACCESSOR`` is ``WrapperTraits``. It's not clear to me what makes this latter case so different.

Comment: Your answer to the second part does indeed make me happy! In practice I have a number of unrelated classes that behave like ``Wrapper``, so I want expressions like ``WrapperTraits<WrapperA<WrapperB<WrapperC<int>>>>::RootType`` to evaluate to ``int``, but your solution can be extended to this case by simply specialising ``Unwrap`` for each ``WrapperX`` class. I've +1'd your answer, but haven't accepted it because it doesn't answer the main thing my question asked about (i.e. the first part).

Comment: @Ose Glad you liked the second part, and while I was about to clarify the first part Casey already answered that (+1 for him) :)